# Working example for KineticGWT built with Maven

Tags: gwt, maven

Does anybody have a working maven project which uses KineticGWT?

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from the developer of KineticGWT. He has a sample file at here https://github.com/neothemachine/glge-gwt-sample/blob/master/pom.xml